# Gatsby API Request on Build Time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have a gatsby project where I need to make an API request to fetch a list of cars that I will use to dynamically create pages for each car. The API response data is like so:

```
{
  "Fleet_Data": [
      {
          "Make": "Honda",
          "Model": "Pilot"
      },
      {
          "Make": "Honda",
          "Model": "CRV"
      },
      {
          "Make": "Honda",
          "Model": "Accord"
      }
  ]
}
```

I am using the [gatsby-source-custom-api](https://github.com/AndreasFaust/gatsby-source-custom-api) plugin. Here's my `gatsby-config.js` file:

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-source-custom-api",
  options: {
    url: "https://api.fleetdata.com/",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic API_KEY'
    },
    rootKey: "Fleet_Data",
    schemas: {
      Fleet_Data: `
                    Make: String
                    Model: String
                `
    }
  }
}
```

I don't have anything in my node file except for debugging but here's my `gatsby-node.js`

```
const path = require("path");

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql }) => {
  console.log("IT WORKED")
};
```

But when I run `gatsby build` I get the following error in the console:

```
"gatsby-source-custom-api" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

invalid json response body at https://api.fleetdata.com/ reason: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 4

  23 |
  24 |   const URL = getUrl(process.env.NODE_ENV, url)
> 25 |   const data = await fetch(URL).then(res => res.json())
     |                ^
  26 |
  27 |   const typeDefs = getTypeDefs(schemas, imageKeys)
  28 |   createTypes(typeDefs)

File: node_modules/gatsby-source-custom-api/gatsby-node.js:25:16



  FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api.fleetdata.com/ reason: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 4
  
  - index.js:272 
    [ProjectCars]/[node-fetch]/lib/index.js:272:32
  
  - task_queues.js:95 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5
  
  - gatsby-node.js:25 Object.exports.sourceNodes
    [ProjectCars]/[gatsby-source-custom-api]/gatsby-node.js:25:16
  
  - api-runner-node.js:429 runAPI
    [ProjectCars]/[gatsby]/src/utils/api-runner-node.js:429:16
  

not finished source and transform nodes - 3.913s
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by a simple fetch api call in the `gatsby-node.js` file instead of using the plugin. The `gatsby-source-custom-api` plugin does not seem to be intended to be used for this particular case despite its name and documentation..

Answer (score 0):

Normally this issue is caused by an `undefined` API response, typically caused by server downtime, wrong configuration, etc.

In your case, I've tested it using Postman and it throws an error: https://api.fleetdata.com/ is not responding so because your are not wrapping it in a `try/catch` or capturing the exception, it fails because the plugin can't fetch the data.

Alternatively, since you are delegating your implementation to a third-party plugin, I don't think there's a way to fix this issue without making a PR or tweaking/customizing the plugin. Your implementation is quite "basic" or standard so to fix it, you may need to open a thread to the author's repository.

You can always add a `fetch` request to your API and customize the given nodes accordingly.

Comment: But where would I wrap the try catch? This is using a gatsby's plugin and per the github documentation there's no place to put the try catch within the plugin configuration

Comment: Well, not you, the plugin. The fact is that the request is throwing a `FetchError` because it's not able to get data from the API. I haven't been able to make a GET request to that API using your parameters (even accessing directly to https://api.fleetdata.com/. The API seems to be down. Your configuration looks fine but the API is not responding

Comment: For security concerns, I did not post the full url. It's just a place holder to represent an API endpoint. I am able to ping and retrieve json data just fine using postman

Comment: Oh, I get it. Try customizing the headers to accept only JSON responses

Comment: I added `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` to the header but still no luck, same error